# Not able to execute command "make clean" from java program

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to execute make clean command from a Java program.I need to change the directory first and then execute it.Or is there any other method?
I have tried both the ways as stated in the site.
1. using ProcessBuilder

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("make "," clean");
pb.directory(new File("\\home\\p\\lipta-v1-3"));
pb.start();
```

1. Using Runtime

   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   String command="make clean";
   process=runtime.exec(command,null,new File("/home/p/lipta-v1-3"));

However none of them are working.The other commands such as cp ,rm etc.are working fine.
I am using Netbeans7.0.1 and ubuntu 12.04

Comment: does the command work when you run it from a console and having the directory `/home/p/lipta-v1-3` as working directory ? also for process builder you should use `"/home/p/lipta-v1-3"` with forward slash instead of backward

Comment: Define not working. Also, you should be using forward slashes in your path, as mentioned by @A4L.

Comment: I tried with forward slash also. It wasnt working.

Comment: Yes the command runs from the directory /home/p/lipta-v1-3

Comment: with the help of a Shell Script file I am performing certain operations on a c File whose output get stored in another c file. Now, I need to run make clean command before performing the same operation on a different C File otherwise I get the previous  output. When the make clean command is not working I am not getting the updated output.

Comment: does "make clean" work from the command line?

Comment: yes it works from the terminal.

Comment: Its working using shell Script. However its not working by the above stated methods.
    
    In shell script foo.sh:
    
    #!/bin/sh
    cd /home/p/lipta-v1-3
    make clean
    
    In the Java Program-
    
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash" ,"/home/abc/foo.sh");
    Process process=pb.start();